# why to implements Comparator<t> not simply Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

```
class problemsolver implements Comparator<Student> {

   public int compare(Student obj1,Student obj2) {
       return obj1.fname.compareTo(obj2.fname);
   } 
}
```

When I write simply `class problemsolver implements Comparator` it is showing this error.

> prog.java:25: error: problemsolver is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Object,Object) in Comparator

Why?

Comment: `Comparator` or `Comparator<Object>` requires a signature `compare(Object o1, Object o2)`

Comment: Because Comparator has a generic type parameter, and leaving that out is wrong. Learn about generics, in while doing so, you also learn why to not leave them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicitely `Comparator` is `Comparator<Object>`, then compiler expects you to implements `compare(Object, Object)`.

What you need is :

```
class problemsolver implements Comparator<Student>
```